# How to position TopLevel Window in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to position my Top Level Window just to the right of my Root Window.
Something like this → ❏❏

> This is the code for my root window

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry("+100+100")
root.update() 
root_width = root.winfo_width()
root_height = root.winfo_height()
root_xoffset = root.winfo_x()
root_yoffset = root.winfo_y()
```

> And this the code for my TopLevel window

```
newWindow = Toplevel(pady=10)
newWindow.geometry(f"+{root_width+root_xoffset}+{root_yoffset}")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `.winfo_x()` and `.winfo_width()` to get the offsetx of the toplevel window.
Like:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.update() # to get the height and the offset of Tk window
toplevel = tk.Toplevel()
toplevel_offsetx, toplevel_offsety = root.winfo_x() + root.winfo_width(), root.winfo_y()
padx = 0 # the padding you need.
pady = 0
toplevel.geometry(f"+{toplevel_offsetx + padx}+{toplevel_offsety + pady}")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: In case you want to move the *toplevel* window along with *root* window use `root.transient(toplevel)`.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque: I test it with the code and `root.transient(toplevel)` doesn't work with the `root.update()` but if we do `toplevel.transient(root)` it works fine. Why is that?

Comment: None of these work for me! Btw I am triggering the toplevel window on click of a button inside a function, if that's causing any issues @Saad

Comment: I have updated my question above please have a look!

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee: If you're creating the *toplevel* window after the `mainloop()` *(creating dynamically)* then you don't need `root.update()` and `toplevel.transient(root)` is working just fine even if you create the *toplevel* window from a button.

Comment: @Saad Ya Thanks a lot, it works! Actually I was making a small typo. Please upvote the question.

Answer (score 1):

The following code places the root window to the top-left of the device-window without changing its default height and width:

```
root.geometry('+0+0')
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35411747)